# Polymer Catalog Website broken on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, polymer, polymer-1.0

On a Ubuntu box I'm facing the problem that the [polymer catalog website](https://elements.polymer-project.org/) doesn't work anymore. The error in firefox 38.0 is:

```
TypeError: item is null in elements.build.js (Zeile 39681)
return item.source + '#' + item.target;
```

And in chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of null
elements.build.js:39681
```

I tried refreshing, restarting, cleaning cache, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser update!

With firefox version 39 and chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit) I don't have this problem anymore.